# my code is doing the opposite

Tags: php

my code is doing the opposite of what i want it to do,im trying to create a simple captcha when i enter the values or letters on the captcha and the username/name if the captcha letters are correct i want it to print `hi $name,you types the correct captcha` and if the data entered is wrong i just want it to print `nooo`.my problem is that when i enter the correct letters or data its printing noo and when i just leave it blank without entering any data its printing `hi $name,you types the correct captcha`

this my simple code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> captcha test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if (isset($_SESSION['real'])) {
    $real = $_SESSION['real'];
}
$guess = $_POST['captcha'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$real = "";
if ($real == $guess){

echo "hi $name,you types the correct name";
} 
else {

    echo "Nooo";
}

} else {
?>
<form action= 'index.php' method='post'>
your name:<input type = 'text' name='name' />
<br />
<img src= 'image.php'>  <input type='text' name='captcha' />
<br/>

<input type= 'submit' name='submit' value='go' />
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **WARNING!** You're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input right back out. This can create a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability, easily allowing malicious users to hijack your site for their own purposes. Please add appropriate validation to user input and filtering on output of user-provided data.  I realize that this looks like you're working on a simple learning exercise, but best practices are best learned *early.*

Comment: `$real` is also null. so when you match with null you get the message.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh i used the $real=""; because i was having an error,undefined variable real....

Comment: @theuserkaps : to avoid undefined `$real` issue, keep the `$real=""` above the if block where you set it.

Comment: @theuserkaps : OR `$real = (isset($_SESSION['real'])) ? $_SESSION['real'] : "";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning a blank value to variable `$real` after you assigned a real value to it before.

`$real = "";`

Comment: i used the $real=""; because i was having an error,undefined variable real..ok now im  getting confused

Comment: $_SESSION['real'] is not set. Set it somewhere before you try to use it... Your code is not doing the "opposite", it's doing EXACTLY what you want it to.

Comment: i have set it i used this code if (isset($_SESSION['real'])) {
    $real = $_SESSION['real'];
}

Comment: No you don't. You did NOT set $_SESSION['real']. If you don't believe me, append this to the if statement:
else { echo '$_SESSION[\'real\'] is not set'; }

Comment: @theuserkaps : just simple dude.. keep the initialisation above if with `$real = $_SESSION['real'];`

Comment: That simply will not work, because $_SESSION['real'] is not set. Unless OP set it in a different file beforehand.

Comment: @DavidHarris : he is using `$real= ""` to avoid undefined `$real` error. i suggested him to move the initialisation above the if block. Now is that an issue?

Comment: No it's not, but he clearly wants $_SESSION['real'] to be the value of $real, telling him to set it to nothing to hide an error won't help him.

Comment: @DavidHarris : if that is the point, why cant you propose him to use the $_SESSION['real'] itself wherever $real is used? there is no use for that also?

Comment: $_SESSION['real'] is not set as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

you are making `$real=""` before the `if` condition check